# calculating age using date and string type values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

From API response I am storing dates in a list.
I want to calculate the age using the list of dates values by the current date. Date is coming in string type in the list. That is why I am getting the below error.

Date Format - (YYYY-MM-DD)

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Here, what I am trying to do:-

```
name= ['Joes','Piyush','Marcus']
birthdate=['2000/02/01','2001/12/02','1999/04/02']

from datetime import date
today = date.today()

for n, bday in zip(name, birthdate):
  age = (today - date(bday)).years
  print("Student ", n, "age is ", age, "years old.")
```

Comment: I recommend that you check out the `datetime.strptime()` function.

Comment: Is 02-03-2022 Februrary 3rd or March 2nd? That date format is notoriously ambiguous. PSA: YYYY-MM-DD doesn't even have to be converted to be compared, it has built-in sortability.

Comment: When I [copy/paste your code](https://replit.com/@codeguru/DryJuvenileAmpersand) and run it, I get a different error: "NameError: name 'auth_response_json' is not defined". If you still need help after googling "python strptime", please create a [mcve] that I can run to reproduce the error you are asking about and I'll be glad to help further.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I tried it like; datetime.strptime(date_string, format). But getting error while calculating age.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the current version of your code and the current error message.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, You can put list on names in place of 'auth_response_json', code works something like that. 
name= ['Joes','Piyush','Marcus']
birthdate=['02/26/2000','12/02/2001','04/21/1999']

from datetime import date
today = date.today()

for n, bday in zip(name, birthdate):
  age = (today - date(bday)).years
  print("Student ", n, "age is ", age, "years old.")

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @tadman that is a list of date. Here date is coming in string type("DD-MM-YYYY")

Comment: If you're getting `02/26/2000` it's probably MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: @slothrop Or a data entry error! In this case the data is completely ambiguous. This formatting is especially frustrating on food packaging where both MM/DD and DD/MM are used.

Comment: Edited the question for better understanding. @slothrop

Comment: @tadman quite true! (fellow YYYY-MM-DD enthusiast here)

Comment: @adiSF thanks, anyway, `datetime.strptime()` should be the way to go. If that's not working, can you tell us what errors you get?

Comment: @slothrop I am getting type error. "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: @adiSF but that's not using `strptime(bday, date_format)`, right? That's doing `date(bday)` - which will indeed fail, because `data` won't accept a string.

Comment: age = (today - datetime.strptime(c_date, "%Y-%m-%d")).years. 
I am trying this way, but getting ValueError (ValueError: time data 'id' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d') @slothrop

Comment: If the date formats are as in your question, then the format string should be `%Y/%m/%d`. But also, the error message suggests the value of `c_date` is the string `"id"` (which obviously cannot be parsed into a date).

Comment: Thanks for the updated code example. This is something we can work with to help you. Note that you can simplify your code even more by using only one date instead of a list. In addition, you can remove the `name` list completely because it has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, date
birthdate=['2000/02/01','2001/12/02','1999/04/02']
today = date.today()
for i in range(len(birthdate)):
    covert_date = datetime.strptime(birthdate[i], '%Y/%m/%d').date()
    differnce = (today - covert_date).days
    age = int(differnce/365)
    day = differnce%365
    print("STUDENTS", i+1, "age is ", age, "years and ",day," days old.")
```

**STUDENTS 1 age is  23 years and  118 days old.**

**STUDENTS 2 age is  21 years and  178 days old.**

**STUDENTS 3 age is  24 years and  58 days old.**

1. converts each string date to a datetime object using the strptime()
   function. The **'%Y/%m/%d'** argument specifies the expected format
   of the string date.
2. The .date() method is called on the datetime
   object to extract only the date part, discarding the time
   information.
3. Finally calculate the age and print it